# How do I give HTTP connections higher priority in TP-LINK TD-8901G modem?

Tags: internet-connection, modem, user-interface, qos

I have a [TP-Link TD-W8901G modem](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TD-W8901G.html). My web browsing/surfing speed decreases when I'm transferring files between other computers which are connected to this modem, and when a torrent client is downloading from 20+ seeds. I want to give the HTTP connections (port 80) the highest priority possible, so that my connection isn't delayed when non-HTTP connections are active.

The interface of the modem related to QoS settings are as below:

[image: QoS settings under the modem interface]

The settings in the image are for "Rule index #1" (notice the "rule index" line in the image). I can define many independent rules for different applications/ports/IPs. The solution may be prioritizing the HTTP port (80) connections, or two separate rules for delaying torrent and file transfer connections.

I thought that it is related with QoS settings, so I posted a screenshot of that part of the modem interface. If it is related to another setting, please leave a comment and I will edit my post supplying the information you asked for.

---

Information about my environment:

- Modem product ID: TP-LINK TD-8901G
- Modem firmware version: 3.0.1 Build 100901 Rel.23594
- Modem hardware version: 3.1
- My OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
- My physical port: Enet1 (Eternet #1)
- My local IP: 192.168.1.2
- My torrent port: 5002
- IP of the computer I'm transferring files between: 192.168.1.4
- Physical port of the computer I'm transferring files between: Enet 2 (Eternet #2)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. And QoS and priority settings won't work. Why? Because the pipe that's congested it the pipe from your ISP *to* you. And your ISP chooses what packets to put on that pipe. So by the time the packet gets to you, the earliest your QoS or priority settings can do anything, it's already too late.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1416348

Does your router support setting bandwidth speeds? you might be able to tag traffic, but not prioritize it. You could also try forwarding particular traffic into different queues to see if it helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.